# SQL import error foreign key check

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, sql, query

I am trying to import sql file but it gives error

```
Error
There is a chance that you may have found a bug in the SQL parser. Please examine your query closely, and check that the quotes are correct and not mis-matched. Other possible failure causes may be that you are uploading a file with binary outside of a quoted text area. You can also try your query on the MySQL command line interface. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem. If you still have problems or if the parser fails where the command line interface succeeds, please reduce your SQL query input to the single query that causes problems, and submit a bug report with the data chunk in the CUT section below:
----BEGIN CUT----
eNoljcEKwjAQRPecr9gPaENSEsSIh1BiW0ybmlRBL0KxBy89WdC/d7XsYWaWfbMuxhANlhLLAr3r
DEosUG9YGmgNjLWfdPIGNddcyVws4zK/FsGl4kJxyc4pYkgZ2sp1Q4YXR5R/zssb23BrvLdECta3
1iARXIrHNErW1/3vNAtpbd7mci1WXK8487arDE4z+79HWCeBg4H0AAEi+QYq6OAOR/JX0hJqciXl
BHsQsPsCe+gxtQ==
----END CUT----
----BEGIN RAW----

ERROR: C1 C2 LEN: 1 2 57
STR: 

MySQL: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
USR OS, AGENT, VER: Linux MOZILLA 5.0
PMA: 4.0.10deb1
PHP VER,OS: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 Linux
LANG: en
SQL:     SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

----END RAW----

SQL query:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

My sql file is

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_address`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_payment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_status_history`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_track`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_aggregated_created`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`; 
TRUNCATE `tag`; 
TRUNCATE `tag_relation`; 
TRUNCATE `tag_summary`; 
TRUNCATE `wishlist`; 
TRUNCATE `log_quote`; 
TRUNCATE `report_event`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_status_history` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_track` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_payment_transaction` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_tax` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_tax_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `tag` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `tag_relation` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `tag_summary` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `wishlist` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

there is any way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the space on first line on your mysql

Comment: I have tried but error still remains.

Comment: Try to set default charset to UTF8

Comment: i have tried but not solve issue.

Comment: What is the command you gave for setting database charset??

Comment: i have using geany ui for set.

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE database_name DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8` First run this comand with replacing database name. Then run your query

Comment: thanks for sharing your knowledge but doesn't solve issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import your `sql` through `mysql` console. Its worked for me.

```
mysql -u root -p magento_test < /your/path/import.sql
```

Comment: i don't want to import using command. i want to from UI. there is no big file that issues that. so i want real solution for all time. +1 for your response. thanks buddy.

Comment: Which utility you used for database import?

Comment: phpmyadmin any suggetions?

Comment: Is your import file successfully uploaded in `phpmyadmin`?